# In python, what's the best way to get the unique count of rows in a dataframe that fall within a specific date-window relative to each row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe like the first 2 columns (`count` & `dt`) below, I'm looking to get the number of distinct `dts` seen in the 7-day window leading up to (but not including) each `dt` (e.g. what’s displayed in `num_distinct_dts_prior_7_days`).

```
 ix count          dt   num_distinct_dts_prior_7_days
0       6  2017-12-01                               0
1       2  2017-12-02                               1
2       2  2017-12-04                               2
3       9  2017-12-05                               3
4       4  2017-12-10                               2
5       7  2017-12-14                               1
6       2  2017-12-28                               0
7       3  2017-12-29                               1
```

This is a simplified version of the table; ultimately, my dataframe would have an additional `id` column, and I'd want to find the number of distinct `dts` seen in the 7-day window leading up to each `dt`, *for each `id`*. I'm happy to iterate over each `id` (*O(tends of thousands)*) if there's no solution applicable across the full dataset.

Comment: Is the `dt` column unique

Comment: The `dt` column would be unique for each `id` (e.g. for every `id` we have a list of unique `dt`s with `count` values.

Answer (score 1):

`3` will be the median of range of `7` numbers , so we can use

```
df['expected'] = 3-(3 - df.groupby(df.index // 7).cumcount()).abs()

  ix  count          dt  num_distinct_dts_prior_7_days  expected
0   0      6  2017-12-01                              0         0
1   1      2  2017-12-02                              1         1
2   2      2  2017-12-04                              2         2
3   3      9  2017-12-05                              3         3
4   4      4  2017-12-10                              2         2
5   5      7  2017-12-14                              1         1
6   6      2  2017-12-28                              0         0
7   7      3  2017-12-29                              1         0
```

Comment: To get he output you posted you might need to use `6` in place of `7`, that might be a typo.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a generalizable approach? For instance, when I have a dataframe with a continuous set of dates from 12/1/2017 through 12/29/2017, this ends up just cycling through a `[0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0]` pattern of outputs, when it should increment up to `7` through the first 7 rows, and then all subsequent rows should *also* be `7` since we have a continuous date range.

Comment: I'm not good at understanding words, it would be better if you update the question with expected output,  I had the general solution using groupby median but thought this would be enough. So update the question for more generalized solution.